# Switching $H_0$ and $H_1$ by replacing $p$ with $1 - p$

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value, intuition

I was reading the source code of `tseries::adf.test`, and it writes

```
if (alternative == "stationary")
    PVAL <- interpol
else if (alternative == "explosive")
    PVAL <- 1 - interpol
else stop("irregular alternative")
```

Here, $H_0$ and $H_1$ is switched by simply replacing $p$ with $1 - p$. To me this is mind-blowing and I cannot figure out an intuitive explanation of this technique. Could someone explain the rationale? Also, is it specific to the ADF test, or is universally correct?

---

Actually, I'm starting to get suspicious! Very crudely speaking, the $p$-value is $P(X \ge x|H_0)$ (this is clearly not true but you get the idea), where $x$ stands for the observation. Then $1 - p$ would be $P(X < x|H_0)$, but this doesn't have to be $P(X \ge x|H_1)$ in my opinion. I would be really surpised if someone can prove they are always equal.